# Customized error message in job repository in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch with quartz scheduler. We are storing job details in database. If any error happens then the error details are storing in Postgresql database tables(BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION, BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS, BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION,BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT). The error details are storing as exception prinStackTrace() details. How can we override those error message? If we write user defined Exception class, then how we can store only error message instead of entire error stack trace?

Comment: It seems you tried to edit Michael's answer to add more information. StackOverflow is not a forum. If you want to provide more information you can use comments below the answer, or even better, edit your own question.

Answer (score 0):

That stack trace comes from the JobExecution's ExitStatus or StepExecution's ExitStatus respectively.  You can set the corresponding ExitStatus to a custom value if you'd like via a listener (typically a JobExecutionListner or StepExecutionListener).

Comment: I need those customized error message need to store in database also. jobRepository is handling all insertions, updations. If i alter error message to customized value, is it reflect in database also??

Comment: The ExitStatus is persisted in the JobRepository (database).

Answer (score 0):

I got it. in JobExecution listener i am updating ExitStatus for each StepExecution. Then it is reflecting in database also. Thank you.